# Error messages displayed when a test fails using MochaJs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am using Mocha with chai to perform unit testing. But I can't comprehend the error messages displayed when a test fails.

For instance, I have a simple api, that only accepts alpha characters for certain inputs. If the user attempts to submit something like "3rror", the api will return a status of 403, or some other error code.

With Mocha I can assert something like : `response.should.have.status(403);` to check the server is catching and serving invalid requests appropriately.

However; with Mocha, I am completely lost when trying to reason out why or what caused an error to occur. Did I write a bad test, did my sanitization/validation middleware fail, am I even connected to my server, or am I failing to handle invalid requests and/or errors appropriately?

Below is an example of an error message Mocha provides for the mentioned case.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'should')
      at C:\...\test.js:53:43
      at Test.Request.callback (node_modules\chai-http\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:716:12)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules\chai-http\node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:916:18)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

I understand it gave the wrong status code, but these error messages don't really help me understand what went wrong. Did I just goof an write a bad test, or did my app fail? So I am here to ask for help.

How can I better understand these errors reported when a test fails using Mocha?